# What is the proper way to pass a c++ object from one thread to another using boost::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

what is the proper way of passing a C++ object (a map, vector, etc.) from one thread to another? I fear race conditions, stale values, etc. I am using boost threads.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "proper way" is usually a subjective question, though I guess that's up to interpretation.

Comment: In short, I want the receiving thread "sees" the object as it has been passed by the sending thread so that reordering issues or issues resulting from reading stale value do not occur.

Comment: use a queue (either lock free or with proper locking.)?

Comment: I wanted to avoid using a queue, instead I wanted to pass a reference to the object to another therad. This is a restriction made by a library that I use.

Comment: how do you intend to "pass the reference"? You cannot make a second thread magically aware of the existence of this object that you want it to process. The second thread has to know to look somewhere for this object, and the first thread has to know about the same location to put it (i.e. shared state) - which means you cannot avoid synchronizing on that shared state (like I said, it can be done lock free, but involves more effort.) Safest, easiest option is to have a locked queue to which you post self contained objects - which the second thread can read off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends solely of what this object "does". If it's self-contained, i.e. doesn't hold pointers/references to other objects that may be used in the originating thread - there seems to be no problem. If OTOH it **does** contain references to some data that still may be in use in the originating thread - its access should be synchronized.

And, of course, passing a complex object by-value should be avoided.

Comment: I does nothing, it is a message which has been created by a worker thread which is now being passed from the worker to a "sender" thread such that it sends out the message to some peer.